# Detect when Websocket is disconnected, with Python Bottle / gevent-websocket

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, bottle, gevent

I'm using the `gevent-websocket` module with `Bottle` Python framework.

When a client closes the browser, this code

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() { ws.close(); });
```

helps to close the websocket connection properly.

But **if the client's network connection is interrupted**, no "close" information can be sent to the server.

Then, often, even 1 minute later, the server still believes the client is connected, and the websocket is still open on the server.

**Question: How to detect properly that a websocket is closed because the client is disconnected from network?**

**Is there a websocket KeepAlive feature available in Python/Bottle/gevent-websocket?**

---

One answer from [Web Socket: cannot detect client connection on internet disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220006/web-socket-cannot-detect-client-connection-on-internet-disconnect) suggests to use a heartbeat/ping packet every x seconds to tell the server "I'm still alive".   The other answer suggests using a `setKeepAlive(true).` feature. Would this feature be available in `gevent-websocket`?

---

Example server code, [taken from here](https://github.com/zeekay/bottle-websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/chat.py):

```
from bottle import get, template, run
from bottle.ext.websocket import GeventWebSocketServer
from bottle.ext.websocket import websocket

users = set()

@get('/')
def index():
    return template('index')

@get('/websocket', apply=[websocket])
def chat(ws):
    users.add(ws)
    while True:
        msg = ws.receive()
        if msg is not None:
            for u in users:
                u.send(msg)
        else:
            break
    users.remove(ws)

run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, server=GeventWebSocketServer)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a timeout to the receive() method.

```
with gevent.Timeout(1.0, False):
    msg = ws.receive()
```

Then the loop will not block, if you send even an empty packet and the client doesn't respond, WebsocketError will be thrown and you can close the socket.

Comment: I guess this wasn't what you wanted to hear?